# NullPointerException when starting ListActivity

Tags: android, android-context, listactivity

I'm working for hours on an error I get, when I want to start a ListActivity.
Short workaround about what I want to do:
I have a main application with a normal menu, from which I want to start a setting list where the user can add specific settings.

I'm trying to start the ListView like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, FileManagerSettings.class));
```

Then in the on Create method I got the error:

```
        userSettings = deserializeObject();

    if(userSettings.isEmpty())
    {
        userSettings.add(new SettingItem("Camera", android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM, false));
    }
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    Context mContext = this.getApplicationContext(); 
    settingsList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_settings);
    settingsList.setAdapter(new CustomSettingsAdapter(mContext, userSettings));
```

The last line causes the error. For better understanding here the Constructor of the adapter class:

```
     public CustomSettingsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SettingItem> sitems)
 {
     settingsArrayList = sitems;
     mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 }
```

And here is the error from the logcat: (Sorry, don't know how to format it right)

> 04-01 11:07:26.756: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-01 11:07:26.756: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.openintents.filemanager/org.openintents.filemanager.FileManagerSettings}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-01 11:07:26.756: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-01 11:07:26.756: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(375):     at org.openintents.filemanager.FileManagerSettings.onCreate(FileManagerSettings.java:43)

In my thinking the error is caused because the LayoutInflater of the context is null... But I don't know how to get the LayoutInflater then and even don't know if this is really the error...

edit: error log with using setContentView():

> 04-01 12:06:56.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(669): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-01 12:06:56.315: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(669): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.openintents.filemanager/org.openintents.filemanager.FileManagerSettings}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

this is the xml-File:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/settings_list_title"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/settings_header"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a ListView with this id? R.id.list_settings

Comment: You could test witch variable is null... The ListView, the Adapter or the Context.

Comment: In the step when the Adapter is created the code is breaking. The context is not null (but the LayoutInflater from the context). Ok and the ListView seems to be null... Ok, I try on this, perhaps this was all. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findViewById() only returns a valid reference to a View if the layout of the Activty has been set. Looking at the code you have pasted in to your question, it does not appear that you are making a call to

```
setContentView(R.layout.whatever_your_layout_file_id);
```

Your variable settingsList, would then be a null reference

Comment: i tried this before, but i read, that the content view is not necessary when using a ListActivity...

Comment: Any Activity must specify a layout. You can't request that an actiivity find a view by ID if it hasn't generated views by setting the layout. Is R.id.list_settings associated with a ListView? Look at this link: http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Creating-Lists-Using-The-Android-Listactivity/

Comment: I edited the xml above... When I change the code an request the layout-file, which contains the ListView i get another error. (i got that error before, and when searching for a soluttion I found a thread where womeone said, that in a ListActivity the setContentView() Method is not needed... But then i'm trying to find out what this other error means.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can display something in an Activity without specifying the layout file. What thread did you read? Did the person sound credible?
I'm not sure what your other problem is, but this thread is specific to your Null Reference Exception, unless you want to change the post.