# React on Checkbox Click in Cutsom ListView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I'm short before failure, although I believe the solution of my problem isn't that difficult.
I have a `ListView` that is de-/serializing an `ArrayList` of `SettingItems`. Each row in this view contains a two `textview`s and one `Checkbox`. The checkbox state should consider if this item will be observed or not. For the listView code you can check my [previous question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512710/nullpointerexception-when-starting-listacitivity/5512808#5512808)

The particular rows are created in my CustomSettingsAdapter, which is extending a BaseAdapter. Therefore it contains an ArrayList of the SettingItems.

```
    private static ArrayList<SettingItem> settingsArrayList; 
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public CustomSettingsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SettingItem> sitems)
{
    settingsArrayList = sitems;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount()
{
    return settingsArrayList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return settingsArrayList.get(position);
}

public ArrayList<SettingItem> getItemList()
{
    return settingsArrayList;
}

public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.setting_name);
        holder.details = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.setting_detail);
        holder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtName.setText(settingsArrayList.get(position).getName());
    holder.details.setText(settingsArrayList.get(position).getPath());
    holder.cb.setChecked(settingsArrayList.get(position).getState());


    holder.cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    return convertView;
```

My thinking was just to change the ArrayList in the adapter and then give it to Activity, where it can be matched with the original list, which can afterwards normally be serialized. But i don't get it to work, with my knowledge and the things i found in the web.
Much thanks in advance for helping me!
Best Regards Tobi

edit:the onCheckedChangeListener:

```
holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            settingsArrayList.get(position).setState(isChecked);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

tried it also with cd.setID and received the actual position for the ArrayList with cb.getID, but it returns with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
holder.checkBoxListView
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {

            //code for making the listItem invisible.
                }

            });
```

Comment: Ok, this brings me a short step forward i think... But it's still not working, I set now first the ID of the cb appropriate to the actual position. And in the onCheckListener I change the State of the Item with the position matching the Checkbox ID. and call then a notifyDataSetChanged(). What am I still doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: hey first let me confirm what action do you want in the onCheckedChangedListener ? is it to hide the corresponding listitem or delete it from arraylist so that it is not displayed in the ListView?